# How to 'dynamicaly' change between relative paths for debug and compiled versions of a program?

Tags: c++

The problem is trivial and goes as follows: I have a string with relative path somewhere in my code at which I should find a file, say `../folder`, which works just fine in Visual Studio. Unfortunately, when I compile the project and try to run it seperately from .exe, I get an error saying that the file couldn't be found, obviously meaning that the absolute path, the `../`, has changed. 
Can I use a preprocessor directive `#if debug` to solve this?

Comment: _"Can I use a preprocessor directive `#if debug` to solve this?"_ Probably yes, but the value is `DEBUG`.

Comment: If you want a solution to ease development, and not necessarily production of any kind, you should just throw whatever files are proximal to your Release exe in the folder with your Debug one.

Comment: If the problem is "trivial" you should be able to do a better job of describing it and providing some code.

Comment: You are actually in for a bigger world of hurt with relative paths than you expect. A program can be run from ANYWHERE, making relative paths for persistent data next to useless.

Comment: You can set the working directory in your visual studio solution.  That's probably a better option than having some kind of preprocessor magic change your paths.

Comment: @user4581301 Sometime for internal tools (used inside a company) , relative path are appropriate as you might control on where it should be installed.

Comment: Should be installed helps, but nothing prevents the dedicated jerk from running the program from the root folder with an explicit path.